# JBOSS Classloading issue

Tags: java, apache-axis, jboss5.x, axis

When I am putting certain set of jars in /lib of the JBoss profile my application is able to connect to the back-end server using http client(commons-httpclient-3.1) but when I am putting the same set of jars in the application library(web-inf/lib) then the application is throwing null pointer exception. The requirement is to put these jars in Web-Inf/lib. The set of jars are :

1. axiom-api-1.2.7.jar
2. axiom-impl-1.2.7.jar
3. axis2-kernel-1.4.1.jar
4. bcmail-jdk14-130.jar
5. bcprov-jdk14-130.jar
6. bctsp-jdk14-130.jar
7. commons-httpclient-3.1.jar

The stack trace is as follows for failure scenario :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:721)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:542)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:189)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:371)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:209)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:448)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:401)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
```

Kindly help how we can resolve this issue.
Regards,

Comment: Can you confirm which version of java you're using?

Comment: 1.6.0.31 on unix machine and JBOSS 5.1 EAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting the axis2 jars in the JBoss profile lib, the NPE issue is resolved. There is definetely some issues with the jar compability and duplicate jars present but couldnot figure it out.

Anyways the issue is resolved by using the JBoss profile lib instead of application lib.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem you have, but for sure the libraries `bcprov-jdk14-130.jar` and `bctsp-jdk14-130.jar` don't work on java 1.4. You need to use the java 1.5 compatible versions; check here for the downloads: http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html .

The NPE is thrown on this code from [httpclient](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient-3.1/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnection.java.html), ad

```
socket.setTcpNoDelay(this.params.getTcpNoDelay());
```

And I think the problem is that socket is null (which might be a consequence of using the wrong version of bouncy castle). From what I remember, but I might be wrong, http client ensures that all the required parameters are set in HttpConnectionParams, so I don't think  that `this.params.getTcpNoDelay()` is throwing the NPE.

I would recommend you to set up your IDE to do remote debugging in this type of case. I'm sure you'll find it very useful.

Comment: we had use the remote debugging and find that socket is indeed null due to which npe   occurs

Comment: Even after using the latest jars I am getting the same exception as above. Kindly help

Comment: Sorry, Harshit I'm not sure what might be the reason. I would verify that you don't have more than one commons-httpclient library in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Augusto for quick response. We have checked that there are no more than two jars in my application library or elsewhere.